# Data correction in Pandas / Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I need to update Data of a subset of my df with values calculated out of a subset of my dataframe.

| PERSNR | XYZ | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | a | Jan | 0,8 |
| 22222 | b | Jan | 0,2 |
| 22222 | a | Feb | 0,8 |
| 22222 | b | Feb | 0,2 |

i have got a Dataframe with like 8000 PERSNR that looks like this, just with many more columns

For a subset, which i already know (i got a list of PERSNR to filter that) i need to add the Values together, ignoring XYZ

i Can do that with pivot_table and can get another df out of it.

The problem i have got is, that i need to update the values afterwards in my original DF.

My goal is to obtain the following without loosing any other data of my DF.

| PERSNR | XYZ | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22222 | a | Jan | 1,0 |
| 22222 | b | Jan | 0,0 |

in Excel i would do a sumifs on my Value Column on my PERSNR, XYZ and DATE.

and then i would replace my values with vlookup in the Value column and overwrite Values with identifier XYZ "b" with zero. This will always be zero.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a data frame like this:

```
data = {
    "PERSNR": [22222, 22222, 22222, 22222, 55555, 55555],
    "XYZ": ["a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"],
    "DATE": ["Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Jan", "Jan"],
    "VALUE": [0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.2],
}
```

```
   PERSNR XYZ DATE  VALUE
0   22222   a  Jan    0.8
1   22222   b  Jan    0.2
2   22222   a  Feb    0.8
3   22222   b  Feb    0.2
4   55555   a  Jan    0.8
5   55555   b  Jan    0.2
```

1. Merge two data frames: (i) the original minus column `VALUE` and (ii) a data frame where you group on `PERSNR` (assuming there will be more than one value for this; otherwise, this column isn't necessary) and `DATE`, then sum the `VALUE` in each group and reset the index.
2. Set column `VALUE` with `0` where `df["XYZ"] == "b"`.
3. Use `.loc` to do the previous steps only for the selected `PERSNR` values.

```
selected_persnr = [22222]  # add all selected values here

df.loc[df["PERSNR"].isin(selected_persnr)] = pd.merge(
    df.drop(columns="VALUE"),
    df.groupby(["PERSNR", "DATE"])["VALUE"].sum().reset_index(),
)
df.loc[(df["PERSNR"].isin(selected_persnr)) & (df["XYZ"] == "b"), "VALUE"] = 0
```

```
   PERSNR XYZ DATE  VALUE
0   22222   a  Jan    1.0
1   22222   b  Jan    0.0
2   22222   a  Feb    1.0
3   22222   b  Feb    0.0
4   55555   a  Jan    0.8
5   55555   b  Jan    0.2
```

Comment: thanks - this is kind of what i need, but i've got like serveral thousands of different PERSNR in my dataframe and it should just apply to a subset of it. 
like i got PERSNR: 22222, 11111, 12345 and in my dataframe there are PERSNR From 00001 to 55555. Maybe i need to split the data i want to clean from my original dataset, use your method and then add it back to my old dataframe?

Comment: @Mike You can use `.loc` to apply this only to selected values of `PERSNR`. I've updated my answer with an example.